# PowerShell start-process -argumentlist: does not work with cmd.exe but works fine with notepad.exe

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

I'm scripting a .bat file for an event scheduler but I'm having a problem.

`start-process notepad.exe -argumentlist 'C:\test.bat' -verb runas` this works

`start-process cmd.exe -argumentlist 'C:\test.bat' -verb runas` but this just opens a cmd window and does nothing.

`...-argumentlist 'start C:\test.bat'` does not work but still opens a cmd window

`C:\test.bat` this works

The .bat file does not have a problem. My original script is `powershell.exe start-process -windowstyle hidden cmd.exe -argumentlist '/c /min start /b "c:\test.bat"' -verb runas`

It seems that argumentlist doesn't get passed to cmd.exe, unlike notepad.exe.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: To troubleshoot this, simply run the full cmd command options passed to the script, etc. to an admin elevated terminal that way. Work out the syntax that works using the `/k` rather than the `/c` to ensure the output of the command terminal stays up and running. Test both admin elevated and not to see if that's the different per the use of `-verb runas` you are using. Work it out manually using a switches and parameters both admin elevated and not, then incorporate that accordingly in the `-argumentlist` parameter and it should work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was already answered on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366956/running-cmd-exe-through-start-process-but-unable-to-pass-the-command-to-cmd-exe)

Basicly, your syntax for cmd.exe is wrong. From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), you can find that

> /c    Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.
> /k  Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

Your argumentlist should therefor be something of the form `'/c c:\test.bat'`

Comment: you're right. I thought /c or /k were just option